# C# Charts n Graphs

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, graph

Does .NET 3.5 provide any build-in support for charts and graphs for Windows Forms applications?

Comment: i cant find anything on it..i need to draw some graphs..the mscharts of .net3.5sp1 are not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first choice would be MsChart but you say that's not working for you. Maybe check your setup, you have to install several things: SP1, MsChart and a VS2008 plugin. I have listed them [here](http://blog.4dotnet.nl/299/henk-holterman/overig/grafiekjes). Don't mind the Dutch text, just follow the bulleted list of links.

If that still doesn't work, there are alternatives like [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/samples.html)

Answer (score 10):

Yes there is

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

AND

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx

For ASP, I also like [openflashcharts](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/dot-net.php). But it's more of a hassle.

If not you have to go with a 3rd party which costs money like dundas or telerik.